# Orthogonal Polynomials approximation and $L^2(\mathbb(R))$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, approximation-theory, orthogonal-polynomials

I have another basic question, this time about approximation of functions.

Given $(p)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\in \mathcal{A}=\{$all the families of orthogonal polynomials $\}$ and $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then there exist a sequence of real values $c_i$ such that 
$$
f=\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i p_i.
$$

Or in other sense, every family of orthogonal polynomials is a basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

is it true ?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The orthogonal polynomials are orthogonal with respect to some measure (depending on which family of orthogonal polynomials), but **not** Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.  In fact, no nonzero polynomial is a member of $L^2(\mathbb R)$. Since they are not members, they can't be a basis.

For example, the Legendre polynomials $P_n(x)$ are orthogonal for Lebesgue measure on $[-1,1]$.  If $f \in L^2([-1,1])$, there are
coefficients $c_n$ such that  $f = \sum_{n} c_n P_n$ as a member of $L^2([-1,1])$.  It may be that $f(x)$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R$, but
there is no reason to think that the series will converge outside $[-1,1]$, or (if it does happen to converge) that the sum will have anything to do with $f$.

Comment: We might add that a basis of $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is the one of Hermite **functions**, which are the Hermite polynomials times a Gaussian. Maybe this is of interest to the asker.